# ace:row editor doesn't update the backing bean

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I am using Icefaces 3.0. I have row editor in a jsf page as

```
            <ace:rowEditor id="editor" rowEditListener="#{employmentNumberController.updateNumber}" rowEditCancelListener="#{employmentNumberController.cancelUpdateNumber}" />
        </ace:column>
```

On top of the Page I have three booleancheckboxes which are properties of a class ExternalSystemSynchroniser that takes care of synchronisation with external systems, but that is not a part of row editor.

```
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="adSynchronizer" label="Synchronize with Ad" value="#{employmentNumberController.synchronizer.synchronizeAd}">
                        <h:outputLabel for="adSynchronizer" value="Synchronize with Active Directory"/>
                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="mcdSynchronizer" label="Synchronize with Mcd" value="#{employmentNumberController.synchronizer.synchronizeMcd}">
                        <h:outputLabel for="mcdSynchronizer" value="Synchronize with Mcd"/>
                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

The problem is when I change the values for these booleans on jsf page....The backing bean properties doesn't get updated and row submit event doesn't work as expected.

How can I make the backing bean change its values when row edit action is submitted.